# beamer, table of contents covered by footer

Tags: beamer

Using beamer, the last line of my table of content is covered by the footer. Any suggestions about how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{ {charts/} }
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle[allowpagebreak]{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents
}

\section{Entwicklung Spaniens von den Anf"angen bis 1982}
\subsection{Spanien bis zur Zweiten Republik (1931)}
\subsubsection{Spanien bis 1469}
\subsubsection{Aufstieg und Fall Spaniens, 1469-1874}
\subsubsection{Spanien bis 1469}
\subsection{Spanien von der Zweiten Republik bis zum Tod Francos (1931-75)}
\subsubsection{Die Zweite Republik (1931-36)}
\subsubsection{Der Spanische Bürgerkrieg (1936-39)}
\subsubsection{Die Franco-Diktatur}
\subsection{Die Transition}
\subsubsection{Die Transition und das 1978er Regime}
\subsubsection{Von Francos Tod zu Suarez (1975-77)}
\subsubsection{Von den ersten Wahlen zu den zweiten Wahlen (1977-9)}
\subsubsection{Von den zweiten Wahlen zum Kollaps der UCD (1979-1982)}
```

\end{document}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) use of the option `allowframebreaks` is evil ... but only to be aware for possibility to (automatically) break table of contents on two slides:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Entwicklung Spaniens von den Anf"angen bis 1982}
\subsection{Spanien bis zur Zweiten Republik (1931)}
\subsubsection{Spanien bis 1469}
\subsubsection{Aufstieg und Fall Spaniens, 1469-1874}
\subsubsection{Spanien bis 1469}
\subsection{Spanien von der Zweiten Republik bis zum Tod Francos (1931-75)}
\subsubsection{Die Zweite Republik (1931-36)}
\subsubsection{Der Spanische Bürgerkrieg (1936-39)}
\subsubsection{Die Franco-Diktatur}
\subsection{Die Transition}
\subsubsection{Die Transition und das 1978er Regime}
\subsubsection{Von Francos Tod zu Suarez (1975-77)}
\subsubsection{Von den ersten Wahlen zu den zweiten Wahlen (1977-9)}
\subsubsection{Von den zweiten Wahlen zum Kollaps der UCD (1979-1982)}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If something does not fit on a slide, the slide is obviously too full.

- You could reduce the amount of text on the slide, either by not showing the subsubsections (`\tableofcontents[subsubsectionstyle=hide]`) or by choosing shorter titles.
- use a plain frame to gain a bit more space
- use another theme. From all the standard themes, `Berlin` is probably the one which consumes the most space

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{ {charts/} }
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents[subsubsectionstyle=hide]
\end{frame}

\section{Entwicklung Spaniens von den Anf"angen bis 1982}
\subsection{Spanien bis zur Zweiten Republik (1931)}
\subsubsection{Spanien bis 1469}
\subsubsection{Aufstieg und Fall Spaniens, 1469-1874}
\subsubsection{Spanien bis 1469}
\subsection{Spanien von der Zweiten Republik bis zum Tod Francos (1931-75)}
\subsubsection{Die Zweite Republik (1931-36)}
\subsubsection{Der Spanische Bürgerkrieg (1936-39)}
\subsubsection{Die Franco-Diktatur}
\subsection{Die Transition}
\subsubsection{Die Transition und das 1978er Regime}
\subsubsection{Von Francos Tod zu Suarez (1975-77)}
\subsubsection{Von den ersten Wahlen zu den zweiten Wahlen (1977-9)}
\subsubsection{Von den zweiten Wahlen zum Kollaps der UCD (1979-1982)} 
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer! what about to use `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks] \frametitle{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}`?

Comment: @Zarko `allowframebreaks` is evil :) But please go ahead and post an answer if you like.

Comment: well, in documentation is warning that it should be used primarily for bibliography ...